# php parameters passed inside function is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

In php/wordpress I have made a function. I want to pass some parameteres inside the function so that it will show result according to that. So far now my function code is like this

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
function check_user_access($role, $action = NULL ) {
    if( $role == 'subscriber') {
        if( $action = 'check_customer' ) {
            $check_customer = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `table1` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
            return $check_customer;
        }

        if( $action = 'check_users' ) {
            $check_users = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `table2` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
            return $check_users;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am using this function like this

```
$role = 'subscriber';
$check_customers = check_user_access($role, $action = 'check_users' );
if( $check_users <=1 ) {
    //do something;
}
if( $check_users > 1 ) {
    //do something other;
}
```

But its showing the result of `$action = 'check_customer'`. Means its working for the first block condition. Can someone tell me how to solve this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: You're using `=` instead of `==`, which means you're *assigning* the value instead of *comparing* it.  The result of an assignment is always `true`, so your first nested `if` condition will always pass.

Comment: @David I think it should be `$action == 'check_customer'` ?

Comment: @NewUser: Yes, use `==` for comparison.  Just like you do in your first `if` statement.

Comment: I don't really like reading Yoda Conditions but I can kinda see the point - they sidestep this issue completely... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Answer (score 2):

change your

```
 if( $action = 'check_customer' ) {}
```

to

```
if( $action == 'check_customer' ) {}
```

`=` means **Assignment Operator**

`==` means **Comparison Operator**

> refer - [from here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)